# How to tell if a key on S3 has "reached eventual consistency"

Tags: amazon-s3, blobstore, eventual-consistency

S3 is eventually consistent, which means that a listbucket operation may or may not see a file depending on, at the very least, which replica you happen to connect to.  My understanding is, at some point, a key is sufficiently replicated (or replayed or indexed or something) that all listbuckets will see it forever more (at least until you delete it).

My question is, is there a way to ask S3 if a given file is in that state, or block until it is?

Bonus question 1:
Is the answer different when it comes to the files contents, that is, if I replace a file, will all reads be guaranteed to see the new version.

Bonus question 2:
What about Google and Azure's blob storage equivalents?
What about Ceph, Minio, CleverSafe, etc?